# What is the difference between these 2 TCP packet captures? One doesn't work

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet-capture

Senario 1:  TCP string containing "PV_MOTION_ON" is sent by a simple utility like PacketSender to an automation program for parsing TCP strings.  It works perfectly.

[image]
[Scenario 1 WireShark PCAP File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zspzfjnoc3exdi/WS_Scenario_1_PacketSender_TCP.pcapng?dl=0)

Scenario 2:  The exact same TCP string is sent from an IP Camera.  The TCP parsing utility only sees a connection being made, and then dropping with no payload data.

[image]
[Scenario 2 WireShark PCAP File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1376rff4va6dmfo/WS_Scenario_2_Axis_TCP.pcapng?dl=0)

I'm not good enough to see the functional difference.  Any ideas on what's going on??

Note:  192.168.2.150 is the RECEIVING the packets in both scenarios

Comment: Sorry about that.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what this "TCP parsing utility" is but I assume it is something which does not work on the normal TCP stack but instead has either some custom stack (i.e. some embedded system with minimal stack) or tries to capture traffic and process it manually - but wrong.

The difference between these two pcap's is that PacketSender first does the TCP handshake and only then sends the data while the Axis sends the data already within the last packet of the handshake:

```
    PacketSender            Axis

    > SYN                   > SYN
    < SYN+ACK               < SYN+ACK
    > ACK                   > ACK + "PV_MOTION_ON"
    > "PV_MOTION_ON"
```

It is perfectly valid TCP how the Axis behaves. It is kind of unusual though since typical socket programming techniques don't make it easy to send packets like the Axis does. The problem is still a wrong assumption inside the "TCP parsing utility" about how TCP works.

Comment: Wow, that was an awesome answer - thank you!  The "TCP parsing utility" is a module that runs inside Windows-based automation software that's designed to handle TCP inputs and trigger an event based on string-match.  What's interesting is that the packets also don't work on a completely separate device (an industrial PLC) that also accepts / parses TCP packets.  In fact, in that case it actually disables the TCP listener until it's reset.  So far, only PacketSender has been able to read them correctly.  I'll reach out to both receive-side vendors to investigate.  Thank you again!